# Error while creating a PDF document with PHPexcel+Mpdf

Tags: php

I am trying to create a PDF document using PHPexcel and MPDF library using the below code.But I get the error - "Adobe Reader could not open '01simple-6.pdf' because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged(for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded)." What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli')
    die('This example should only be run from a Web Browser');

/** Include PHPExcel */
require_once '../Classes/PHPExcel.php';
$rendererName = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_MPDF;
$rendererLibrary = 'mpdf.php';
$rendererLibraryPath = dirname(__FILE__).'/../../MPDF56/' . $rendererLibrary;

// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

// Set document properties
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Maarten Balliauw")
                             ->setLastModifiedBy("Maarten Balliauw")
                             ->setTitle("PDF Test Document")
                             ->setSubject("PDF Test Document")
                             ->setDescription("Test document for PDF, generated using PHP classes.")
                             ->setKeywords("pdf php")
                             ->setCategory("Test result file");


// Add some data
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello')
            ->setCellValue('B2', 'world!')
            ->setCellValue('C1', 'Hello')
            ->setCellValue('D2', 'world!');

// Miscellaneous glyphs, UTF-8
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A4', 'Miscellaneous glyphs')
            ->setCellValue('A5', 'éàèùâêîôûëïüÿäöüç');

// Rename worksheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setShowGridLines(false);

// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


if (!PHPExcel_Settings::setPdfRenderer(
        $rendererName,
        $rendererLibraryPath
    )) {
    die(
        'NOTICE: Please set the $rendererName and $rendererLibraryPath values' .
        '<br />' .
        'at the top of this script as appropriate for your directory structure'
    );
}

// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (PDF)
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.pdf"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'PDF');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

Comment: Open the file in your favourite text editor and find out what does not belong there.

Comment: As Alvaro says - in particular, check for leading or trailing spaces, a leading BOM marker, or any obvious plaintext PHP error messages in the file

Comment: Hi, i'm trying to use this library but have no clue where to store this code. Should i create a file? where do i put it?

Answer (score 2):

Try turning off the error reporting. I had the same error, then I saw some notices and warnings that were output before the file output.

So I turned off the error reporting and it started to work .